# joomla 1.5 adminsitrator: article section editing doesn't load

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

The client have moved Joomla from old to new server. I am aware of what they did exactly. As a result joomla webpage is working (it seems so) and administrator panel loads correctly. You can edit menu items etc. there.

However, when you try to edit article it doesn't work. 
When I click on article, the page start to load (...`administrator/index.php?option=com_content&sectionid=-1&task=edit&cid[]=56`), but the only thing that is loaded is empty page with one form element with input fields "Title", "Alias", "Section". That is it. So this means that page stoped loading.

I am not so big expert in Joomla and debugging, but can you suggest me how to fix this issue? How to find out why articles stoped working? I understand that you can me give the exact sollution, but can you mention some steps to investigate.

**EDIT:**
After some investigation I have set

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

in admin.content.html.php and this showed me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check version of php. Joomla 1.5 is pretty old so somewhere it can contain `call-time pass-by-reference` which was removed in 5.4+, so using it raise a fatal error. Enable error_reporting also `error_reporting(E_ALL);  ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout')` or `stderr`

Comment: It uses 5.3.3. and even I changed error_report it doens't show any errors. This is for administration panel.

Comment: @renathy try to set error reporting and display errors in `.htaccess`, maybe there is some fatal error and `ini_set ` doesn't affect. Also maybe not all files have been uploaded correctly. Try to reupload administrator/com_content directory. Also try to disable editor plugin and see will it help, maybe its a plugin issue

Comment: I have found out that this row causes error: echo $editor->display( 'text',  $row->text , '100%', '550', '75', '20' ) ; 

in admin.content.html.php